# How is this minified JS the same as this uncompressed version?

Tags: javascript

So this is what my uncompressed looks like:

```
function extractDropdownValues(){     
  var all_selected = true;
  $('.variant_options select').each(function() { 
      if (this.selectedIndex == 0) {
          all_selected = false;
      }
  });
```

This is the compressed version:

```
extractDropdownValues(){var e=!0;$(".variant_options select").each(function(){this.selectedIndex==0&&(e=!1)});
```

I am confused by the `e=!0` being the equivalent of `all_selected = true` and also by the compressed version of `this.selectedIndex==0` if statement. In the compressed version, it is saying `if` this index == 0, then set it to false.

But in the compressed version, it looks like it is checking for the `selectedIndex` to be equal to 0 AND `&&` for `all_selected = false` (i.e. `e=!1`). But I don't want that as the `if` condition, that should be the result after the `if` condition is satisfied.

Am I reading this wrong?

P.S. The compressed version is not working in production, but the uncompressed is working in dev. I am not sure the two are correlated, but on the surface, they don't seem to be identical to me.

**Edit 1**

As I suspected, I ran the minified JS through a JS prettifier, and this is the result:

```
function extractDropdownValues() {
    var e = !0;
    $(".variant_options select").each(function () {
        this.selectedIndex == 0 && (e = !1)
    });
```

Soo...ahh...WTF is happening here?

Comment: I presume this script is checking that an option other than the first one is selected in each select. Note that if no option is selected, the *selectedIndex* will be -1 and the script will evaluate that is having an option selected (i.e. the *selectedIndex* is not 0). So all the selects could have no option selected and *all_selected* will be set to `true`. The test should probably be `this.selectedIndex > 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

0 in boolean form is false, so the boolean negation of 0 (false) is true.

Similarly, 1 in boolean form is true, so the boolean negation of 1 (true) is false.

`&&` is the short circuiting 'and' operator, meaning that as soon as it knows what its result is it returns immediately - if its first operand is false, it returns false. If its first operand is true, only then it evaluates the second operand and returns that.

So `e=!1` executes only if `this.selectedIndex==0` is true (because if it's false, it KNOWS it's going to return false and aborts early).

Comment: Yeh...i know that. I am not debating that. The boolean logic seems true. The issue is the if statement. I updated the question with the result of prettifying the JS.

Comment: So you are saying that my uncompressed version and the minified version are the same?

Comment: It's also a reason why "minified" is considered a synonym for "obfuscated". These tricks are performed purely to save a few characters, obfuscation is a by product.

Comment: @RobG Tricks like these don't take much effort after you've seen them once. It's the loss of variable names that gets me, personally.

Comment: Fair enough, but the people put onto code maintenance are usually the least experienced so it's good to make life easy for them. Such obfuscation rarely has any tangible benefit, certainly it doesn't help performance significantly and is often slower (though perhaps not perceptibly).